# How to exclude interface property from extended class in typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, generics, inheritance

I have two classes

```
interface IBasicFunctionalityProps {
  propertySpecificForBasicFunctionality: MyType;
  propertyNotSpecificForBasicFunctionality: boolean;
}

class BasicFunctionalityClass extends React.Component<IBasicFunctionalityProps> {...}

class ExtendedFunctionalityClass extends BasicFunctionalityClass
```

`BasicFunctionality` has two props and it's ok.
But in inherited class `ExtendedFunctionalityClass` i don't want to have `propertySpecificForBasicFunctionality` property. How i can omit this property?

Comment: Why do you want to omit the property? Can you give us your real code?

Comment: @Niek unfortunately i can't give any real code example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's totally against concept of inheritance.

In my opinion you should split`IBasicFunctionalityProps` interface into two separate interfaces and implement them as needed. This way you could achieve desired behaviour.

Anyway, React dissuades using inheritance.
https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#so-what-about-inheritance

Best regards

Comment: You are absolutely correct
I thought that `BasicFunctionalityClass` is **basic** and `ExtendedFunctionalityClass` is **not basic** but it turned out the opposite